# Perl verbose output?

Tags: perl

Is there are a way to get Perl debug output, similar to `bash -x` but in Perl?

I do not need strikt or diagnose messages (they compile the code but do not print the line that the Perl interpreter executes).

Comment: There is the debugger. Just run your script with `perl -d`.

Answer (score 15):

Assuming you are using some kind of unix you can use the Devel::Trace perl module.
If it is not installed you can install it from CPAN like this:

```
sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install Devel::Trace'
```

Once you have it you can run your script like this:

```
perl -d:Trace myscript.pl
```

And it will do exactly what bash -x does (note that the name of the Trace package is case sensitive).